# Read Ubuntu files from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, ubuntu, filesystems, ntfs

I have a dual booting Windows 7/Ubuntu 10.04 computer, and I killed the Ubuntu partition (I don't know how, but I can't even boot without it saying that there is a missing file and the kernel panicking).

I want to get the files from my home directory, but all of the programs I have tried don't work. If I try to open `L:/` (the drive I installed Ubuntu into), it works, but only shows 3 folders, `$RECYLCE.BIN`, `System Volume Information` and Ubuntu, none of which contain anything useful. In properties, it says it is NTFS. (I noticed that this is also the contents of `/host`). I have tried 4 different programs, and none have worked ([Explore2fs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explore2fs), Ext2Fsd, [Ext2IFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext2IFS) and DiskInternals' Linux reader).

Comment: There are no modern, reliable ext* drivers for Windows. The last time I say one that worked well, was in the times of Windows XP, and it had some minor issues. I'd recommend the approach Adam suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend actually booting up from a linux live cd, mounting the filesystem, and copying the files to something like a flash drive. Also, this would be better suited for the Ubuntu questions site:
https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: +1, I think this is a much better idea, for the reasons I stated above.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above solution you can mount the windows partition and transfer the files to it directly.